# Event delegation problems

Tags: javascript, event-delegation

I'm learning javascript and having trouble with event delegation. I was testing what I have completed in the browser for errors--not much--and keep getting a message back saying:

> `thumbs.addEventListener` is not a function

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var thumbs = document.querySelectorAll("#thumbnails");
    thumbs.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
             
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="thumbnails">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Battle" title="Battle" />
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Luneburg" title="Luneburg" />
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Bermuda" title="Bermuda" />
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Athens" title="Athens" />
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Florence" title="Florence" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** You're getting the error because you're calling `addEventListener` on the return value of `querySelectorAll` which is a `NodeList` that doesn't have a function called `addEventListener`. Use `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll`.

---

To achieve event delegation, you'll have to set the event listener on one of the ancestors of your elements (for example `#thumbnails`), then when the click happens, check if the target of the event is an image:

```
var container = document.querySelector("#thumbnails");        // select the ancestor, use querySelector instead of querySelectorAll

container.addEventListener("click", function(event) {         // add the click event listener to it
    var target = event.target;                                // when the click happens, get the target of the click
    if(target.matches("img")) {                               // check if the target is one of our img (the selector passed to "matches" could be any css selector, for example "#thumbnails > img", ...)
        console.log(target.title);                            // use the element, or whatever
    }
});
```

**Example:**

```js
var container = document.querySelector("#thumbnails");

container.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var target = event.target;
    if(target.matches("img")) {
        console.log(target.title);
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="thumbnails">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Battle" title="Battle" />
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Luneburg" title="Luneburg" />
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Bermuda" title="Bermuda" />
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Athens" title="Athens" />
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Florence" title="Florence" />
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, that helped. Thank you!

Comment: @LarryHaufle You're welcome! I've also added a **note** regarding the error you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

You're working with `thumbs`, an array. To add an event listener to each one you'll have to loop.

```
  var thumbs = document.querySelectorAll("#thumbnails");
  thumbs.forEach(function(element){
    element.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      // your code
   });
  });
```

> Update

```
  var thumbs = document.getElementById("thumbnails");
    thumbs.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      // your code
      console.log(event.target);
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I was trying to use event delegation or bubbing up through the Dom, so I wouldn’t have to assign an event listener to each.

Comment: Use `getElementById("thumbnails")` to target the `div` as parent.